# Одинаковая высота div в 2 разных секциях по :nht-child

Tags: javascript

Как передать значение `height` из `.rem` в `.tet` - чтобы `.rem - height` 1 строки совпадал со значением `.tet - height` 1 строки и т.д.  - использую псевдоселектор `:nht-child`.

То есть передать значение всех `.rem - height в .tet` - и сохранить порядок строк.

Мало опыта. Понимаю что через цикл - но не могу понять как именно.

Спасибо.

```
<div class="rem" style="height: 20px;"></div>
<div class="rem" style="height: 40px;"></div>
<div class="rem" style="height: 10px;"></div>
<div class="rem" style="height: 60px;"></div>

<div class="tet"></div>
<div class="tet"></div>
<div class="tet"></div>
<div class="tet"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если через цикл, то можно так:

```
var arr_rem = document.getElementsByClassName("rem")
var arr_tet = document.getElementsByClassName("tet")
for(var i = 0; i < arr_rem.length; i++){
    arr_tet[i].style.height = arr_rem[i].style.height
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

Еще вариант

```js
'use strict';

var div1 = document.querySelectorAll('.div1'), 
  div2 = document.querySelectorAll('.div2');

for (var i = 0; i < div1.length; i++) {  
  div2[i].style.height = div1[i].offsetHeight + 'px';
}
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.divs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 15px auto;
  padding: 15px;
}

.divs > div {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.divs:nth-of-type(2) > div {
  background: #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="divs">
  <div class="div1" style="height: 50px;">div 1</div>
  <div class="div1" style="height: 80px;">div 2</div>
  <div class="div1" style="height: 30px;">div 3</div>
  <div class="div1" style="height: 60px;">div 4</div>
</div>
<div class="divs">
  <div class="div2">div 1</div>
  <div class="div2">div 2</div>
  <div class="div2">div 3</div>
  <div class="div2">div 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое